# What is the use of * in Hostname

Tags: sitecore-api

Why we create Site like below in Site definition:

```
  <site name="Test Site">
        <patch:attribute name="hostName">*</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="targetHostName">*</patch:attribute>
      </site>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a user visits site using a host name (ex.xyz.com), sitecore code will go into site definitions, from top to bottom and try to find any matching First site definition for that. but `hostName` is not a required attribute. Default `"website"` doesn't have one either. The host name of the incoming url. May include wildcards *(ex. http://www.site.net, *.site.net, *.net, pda.*, print.*.net)*  It’s possible to set more than one mask by using ‘|’ symbol as a separator *(ex. pda.*|print.*.net)*.

So * in your hostname doesn't have any meaning or you can say allowing all type of URLs.
Sitecore has defined `"website"` site definition in a way, that all the non-matching url request are matched into `"website"` site definition. i.e. by not having `"hostName"` attribute and virtualPath/physicalPath are set to "/".